# Options to provide Type-C Power Delivery from a Type-A host

Tags: power-supply, usb-c, usb-power-delivery

So in my vehicle I have some Type-A ports and those can be used with a phone to get Android Auto. Of course this is the 5V, 500mA standard and this can be enough to have a *small* net power for my Pixel 6 if it's not under load.

The goal is trying to find if I can take a Type-C Power Delivery compatible charger and the Type-A host and merge them together. It seems like this solution maybe exists, [but the Tindie page for it has been out of stock since 2018.](https://www.tindie.com/products/clarahobbs/pd-buddy-wye/)

Plus I have a few friends over the net with some Meta VR headsets losing charge while connected to their desktop. After talking to them it seems like the headsets support Type-C Power Delivery, but many desktops and even my newest motherboard do not support Power Delivery even if it has a Type-C port on it. So anything found here will most definitely help some of my friends too who'd like to stay in VR for extended periods.